# Why would I use $version instead of '2.7.0'?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies

I would like to understand the practise of not putting the version codes in your dependencies.

Why would I choose one practise over the other:

```
dependencies {
   implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
   implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$moshi_version"
   implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
 }
```

vs

```
 dependencies {
   implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
   implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
   implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because it may be that the version is important for several dependencies. For example, like here:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
```

So you only need to adjust the version once and don't run the risk of forgetting a change.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now that it will be useful for larger developments. I have mostly made small things, so was never really valid for me. I understand doing it for the sake of good practise.

Comment: @helpVulcan I'm not sure if it's standard practice, or if it's done in Android projects at all, but in personal projects that have a not-insignificant number of dependencies, I prefer to put the actual versions in a project-level `gradle.properties` file. Then I pull them into the build script (e.g., `val junitVersion: String by project`), which necessarily requires I use variables in the dependency declarations. By putting the versions in the properties file, I find updating the versions no longer necessitates a recompilation of the build script(s), thus reducing build time in some cases.

Comment: I should note that my experience is mostly with the Kotlin DSL. I'm not sure if that would be a benefit when using the Groovy DSL.